# Ajax/PHP login not reacting

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have received a partially built website and was asked to implement a login system for clients and admins. I am quite new to JS and AJAX and I am having a hard time understanding what the other person has implemented and how I can get it to function properly.

This is the login form where the user can enter in the credientials.

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="auth/ajax-auth.php" method="POST" >
    <h4>Client Login</h4>
        <div id="error"></div>
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <input id="username" class="form-control" name='username' placeholder="Username">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name='password' placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" id="loginbtn">Login</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Once the form gets submitted it will run `ajax-auth.php` and also will run an Ajax function. It should then redirect the user who is logging in to either the client side or admin side dependant on their permission level.

The Ajax function looks like this:

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
                      {
var username=$("#username").val();
var password=$("#password").val();
var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "auth/ajax-auth.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){ $("#loginbtn").val('Connecting...');},
        success: function(data){
            if(data) {
                alert(data + " Logged in!");

               if(data == "admin"){
                   window.location.href = "/admin/admin.php";
               }
               else if(data == "client"){

                //uncomment when client_home.php page is ready
                //window.location.href = "client_home.php";

                //for now just redirect to homepage
                window.location.href = "index.html";
               }

            } else {
                $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                $("#loginbtn").val('Submit')
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my PHP:

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);                
ini_set('display_errors', 1);          

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include '../connection.php';
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == true)
    {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row["permission"] == 2)
        {
         $_SESSION["permission"] = 2;
         //Redirect to the admin login page.
         header("Location: ../admin/admin.php");
        }
        else if ($row["permission"] == 1)
        {
        $_SESSION["permission"] = 1;
        $_SESSION["userId"] = $row["user_id"];
        $_SESSION["account"] = $row["account_id"];
        //redirect to the client home page.
        header("Location: ../index.html");   //Change this when ready, for now go to homepage
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "User not found!";
        header("Location: ../index.html");
    }
```

When I enter in a username and password (wrong or right) nothing is happening. If the credentials are wrong my error message should be hitting, and if I am logging in as admin I should be redirected to the admin page, and same with for the client being redirected to the client page.

How/Where am I going wrong here?

The console is not throwing me any errors and even my error message for invalid login creds is not being displayed.

I know I am close, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: first of all either remove `action from your form` or add `e.preventDefault();` in your jquery code.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Why first of all? how about explain why I should do this instead of just telling me to do it.

Comment: since action given to the form then it directly goes to that page. ajax will not work till you do what i said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to give some output in your PHP, because now you're redirecting the request. This won't work for an AJAX request.

For example:

```
    if ($row["permission"] == 2)
    {
      $_SESSION["permission"] = 2;
      // Redirect to the admin login page.
      echo 'admin';
    }
    else if ($row["permission"] == 1)
    {
       $_SESSION["permission"] = 1;
       $_SESSION["userId"] = $row["user_id"];
       $_SESSION["account"] = $row["account_id"];
       echo 'client';
    }
```

Comment: This is echoing "admin" and "client" properly dependant on who I am logging in as and my form is also responding so thats nice, but how can I get it to redirect them instead of just echoing?

Comment: Woops I adjusted my AJAX and forgot to change it back, when I did this logged in and redirected to the proper pages.

Comment: Redirecting is done in your jQuery code. There's no need to do this within PHP.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change some things back to how it originally was in my question, this works thanks! Would you be able to tell me exactly what I was doing wrong - still a bit confused.

Comment: The jQuery code was expecting a response. But the PHP code was redirecting to another page instead of echoing a value. Because your logic is happening in your jQuery part, the AJAX cannot handling the code in the onSuccess event. Just by echoing a value in PHP, this will be fine now.

Comment: Hmm, yes now I think I understand what is going on and where I was going wrong, thanks that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);                
ini_set('display_errors', 1);          

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include '../connection.php';
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == true)
    {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row["permission"] == 2)
        {
         $_SESSION["permission"] = 2;
         //Redirect to the admin login page.
         echo "admin"; die;
        }
        else if ($row["permission"] == 1)
        {
        $_SESSION["permission"] = 1;
        $_SESSION["userId"] = $row["user_id"];
        $_SESSION["account"] = $row["account_id"];
        //redirect to the client home page.
         echo "client"; die;  //Change this when ready, for now go to homepage
        }
    }
    else
    {
          echo "notFound"; die;
    }
```

**And script is like**

```
 $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
                          {
e.preventDefault();
    var username=$("#username").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
    if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auth/ajax-auth.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#loginbtn").val('Connecting...');},
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="admin"||data=="client"||) {
                    alert(data + " Logged in!");

                   if(data == "admin"){
                       window.location.href = "/admin/admin.php";
                   }
                   else if(data == "client"){

                    //uncomment when client_home.php page is ready
                    //window.location.href = "client_home.php";

                    //for now just redirect to homepage
                    window.location.href = "client_home.html";
                   }

                } else {
                    $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                    $("#loginbtn").val('Submit');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, I only get notFound from the else in the PHP, I know for a fact that the user does exist within the db. I tried both a "client" user and an "admin" user.

Comment: @BigRabbit  add datatype:html to your ajax

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line in your php:

```
header("Location: ../index.html");
```

Use this instead:

```
echo $username;
```

This will return the username to the Ajax request so your javascript can then redirect the user upon a successful login.